# in/at [the] implementation

Tags: prepositions, determiners

In the sentence "This can be mitigated at/in [the] implementation by using", should I use at or in? Also, should I put a "the" there?

What I mean by this sentence is that when someone wants to implement the method, the aforementioned problem can be mitigate by using ...

Answer (score 1):

This US English speaker would use **in**.

**At** usually means "at a physical location" or "at a specific point in time", but neither of those is appropriate here.

**In** is more general, and means something like "contained by" or even "associated with".

[You can see that although "in the implementation by" is not a common phrase, "at the implementation by" doesn't occur at all within Google's search corpus!](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20implementation%20by%2Cat%20the%20implementation%20by&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20implementation%20by%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

*For technical language, I would always recommend using the same language and idioms as your colleagues and existing documentation do. So if you have examples of this, the best recommendation is to stick to their standard regardless of how correct it may be.*

---

Either of these can work, but they both have slightly different implications:

> This can be mitigated at implementation...

Here, you're saying that it's not a problem to be dealt with right now - it's something that will be solved when you reach implementation. Note that here, implementation is used to mean "the implementation phase of the project" (a time frame), and not the specific work that is implemented. As an alternative, you could replace "at" with "during" here for the same meaning.

---

> This can be mitigated in the implementation...

In this phrasing, you're saying that the problem will be dealt with by the details of the implementation. Note that this time, implementation refers to the specific work done, and not a time frame. An alternative to this would be "through" or "via", again suggesting it's the specifics of the implementation that will solve the problem.